# Displaying notifications at a certain time with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and Java in general. I'm trying to build an app that, based on whether a checkbox is ticked in the app's settings menu, will display a notification everyday at 8AM.

I've figured out how to display the notification, but not how to trigger it at 8AM. This is the current notification code:

```
    private void addNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cog)
                    .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
                    .setContentText("This is a test notification");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

My questions are two:

1. How do I make the notification trigger at 8AM every day?
2. How do I make the app remember if the checkbox is ticked or not?

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

You can use the `AlarmManager` class to trigger a notification at a particular time. The Android developer website has a great section on how to use it: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#examples-of-real-time-clock-alarms

To help the app remember if the checkbox is checked, `SharedPreferences` should be enough. There's another page on the Android developer website on how to use it: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Would you know if there there any special permissions I need to put in the manifest file?

Comment: In this case, you should be ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

*How do I make the notification trigger at 8 AM every day?*

You can use [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) to achieve this.

*How do I make the app remember if the checkbox is ticked or not?*

Use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) if you want small data to be persisted. Otherwise use databases like [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

Comment: I'll look into that, appreciate the reply!